# Call Sequence of willPresentNotification with UNUserNotificationCenter and UNNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

When there is a `UNNotificationServiceExtension` for the category of the notification, does iOS call `userNotificationCenter: willPresentNotification: withCompletionHandler:` before or after the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `UNNotificationServiceExtension` is called first, THEN the delegate method.